# Power BI Measure filtering with ONLY date

Tags: powerbi, dashboard

I am working on a power bi report to show the Servers' performance against the Restaurant's performance.

I have two main tables: feedback and server
feedback and server tables have cross filter direction of "both"

I have a chart for the names and their served counts and the user can click the servers and the report should change appropriately.

I have 2 main measures: performance indicator for the restaurant and server

I would like to create a Restaurant Performance measure that is ONLY filtered by the time slicer(Timeline), AND does not drill down when I click the name of the servers. I have the following code but it seems my number is off somehow. Any ideas?

`_MEASURE_CSI_TABLETALK = CALCULATE(SUMX(Feedback, [TotalFeedback] * [AverageRating]), ALLEXCEPT(servers, servers[AverageRating])) / CALCULATE(SUM(Feedback[TotalFeedback]), ALLEXCEPT(servers, servers[ServedCount]))`

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem is to handle the interactions between visuals in Report view. 
[image: showing PowerBI ribbon: Format page]

Click the Edit interactions button in the Format page of the ribbon. Now when you select the chart that has the names of the servers, you can change the way that that chart filters all other visualisations on the same page, for the visual which displays your Restaurant Performance measure, click 'None':

[image: showing the options for a visualisation in Edit Interactions mode - 'None' is selected]